# Asking about exceptions to convention or practice

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There have been a couple of situations recently where I have been maintaining code written years ago and someone has used a construction that was confusing to me or just bad practice (e.g. overriding equals but not hashcode in Java.) Is there a way to ask basically: Is there ever a situation in which [weird construction/generally bad practice] makes sense?

Comment: Well, more likely on [programmers.se] than here. Though probably also difficult there...

Comment: It's a fairly broad subject to begin with, and it's also fairly subjective, since one would want to know *why* there is this break in convention.  The real problem is pinning an answer down; in the face of business requirements, an approach may "make sense", but an ideal approach may be elusive even for that platform's architects.

Comment: Close voters why is this on hold? What I am asking is very clear. I asked and I was answered. I appreciate the community response in why what I was saying was wrong. @Servy very clearly responded with the the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Such a question would be primarily opinion based.

Comment: There are some conventions that are simply never ok. For example it is never ok to store passwords in plain text. I haven't found anyone who thinks the hashcode equals thing is ok. These would be questions for which the answer is a fact not an opinion

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot The fact that a given opinion is ubiquitous doesn't make it not an opinion.